# Linearly independent vectors from a family of subspaces

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra

For the proof of a certain combinatorial statement on subsets of ${\mathbb F}_2^n$
in a paper I and several other people are working on, the following statement was helpful.

**Proposition.**
Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$, let $I$ be a finite set, and let
$U_i \subseteq V$ for $i \in I$ be linear subspaces such that
$\dim \sum_{j \in J} U_j \ge \#J$ for each subset $J \subseteq I$.
Then there exists a linearly independent family $(v_i) \in \prod_{i \in I} U_i$.

I have a proof for this, but I also have the feeling that this should be known.

So my question is: Has somebody seen this somewhere, and if so, can you give
a reference?

---

**EDIT:** Following up on Fedor Petrov's answer, I found the original
reference:

R. Rado, *A  theorem on independence relations*, [Quart. J. Math.  Oxford Ser. **13** (1942), 83-89](https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/os-13.1.83).

The statement I was looking for is Theorem 1 there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly Rado theorem on independent transversal (for the corresponding linear matroid).

Strictly speaking, to use it you should deal with finite sets, but a dimension of a vector subspace always equals to a rank of its appropriate finite subset, so there is no problem with it.

Comment: Thanks! There is a [Wikipedia page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_von_Rado) for this theorem of Rado's, but it seems to exist only in German (which is no problem for me tough). In the intended application, we are dealing with finite subsets, so we can probably apply the theorem more directly.